# Are there any certifying entity for deployed source code?

Tags: php, web-applications, deployment, web-deployment, sign

My question is about the deploy. We are having a lot of trouble with clients saying that something that they asked to modify is modified, and after some days it is undone.
We suspect that our (third part) server could be restauring backups with old versions of our code. Internally we use SVN, but it means nothing for the client, and we can't control the files after the deploy with it.

So, we would like a service which would sign our deploy and put a badge on the site with the latest modification date. And, if possible, with a snapshop or MD5 of the files.

Do you know if there are any service like this out there?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of SVN Keyword Substitution to accomplish this http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

So for instance you can use `$Data$` which will be expanded to `$Date: 2006-03-15 02:33:03 -0500 (Wed, 15 Mar 2006) $` on commit. You can then parse that in PHP and display it on your page wherever you want.

Think stackoverflow might do something similar to this if you see the [svnrev div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972244/are-there-any-certifying-entity-for-deployed-source-code/13972297#svnrev) down the bottom.